# How to publish randomized messages from zmq socket using setInterval?

Tags: node.js, setinterval, simulation, zeromq

The following code is written to simulate the zmq socket to send the hard-coded `myData`. 
How to make the setInterval function to send both `myData` & `myData2` randomly? This will help me to simulate the messages from multiple sources (eg: `services`, `IOT devices`) to be published by same socket instance

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var socket = zmq.socket('pub');

//simulated message
var myData = {
  "vmId" :  "abc",
  "vmName" : "myVm"
}
var myData2 = {
  "vmId" :  "xyz",
  "vmName" : "myVm_2"
}
socket.bindSync('tcp://localhost:3000');

setInterval(function(){
 socket.send(['notify_message', JSON.stringify(myData)]);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Math.random()`:

```
setInterval(function() {
  socket.send(['notify_message', 
   JSON.stringify(Math.random() < 0.5 ? myData : myData2)]);
}, 1000);
```